# Returning AspNetUser table data from get request

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-identity, owin

I am using Asp.Net Web Api Identity - Individual User Account. I am returning AspNetUser Table Data from Web API.
Note : This table is made my asp.net itself, not me. But, I changed its connection string to store it in a pre-exiting database in Sql, and now, returning table data causes `Internal Server Error`.

```
public AspNetUser Get(string id)
    {
            using (UserDBEntities entities = new UserDBEntities())
            {
                return entities.AspNetUsers.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName == id);
            }
    }
```

And class for AspNetUser table is default, as individual user account proposes.

**If I do it like below, error still persist on normal run, but not while debugging, that is when I debug the code step-by-step, it works file, and returns correct data, but when I remove my breakpoints and execute OR press continue while debugging instead of going step wise to return statement, it runs into error.**

```
AspNetUser data = entities.AspNetUsers.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName == id);
return data;
```

**Unlike this scenario, Returning without storing data, runs into error in all cases (debugging or not).**

But, I don't understand, why??
how come this can affect anyhow?

Network Error Response Body:=>

```
{"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/json; charset=utf-8'.","ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException","StackTrace":null,"InnerException":{"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"Error getting value from 'AspNetUserClaims' on 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.AspNetUser_4C1FDBB9E07016D6C527FBA4F5785F2C7FE37C77A86A5D1946B99CFFDE56DB7F'.","ExceptionType":"Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException","StackTrace":"   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DynamicValueProvider.GetValue(Object target)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.CalculatePropertyValues(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContainerContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonProperty property, JsonContract& memberContract, Object& memberValue)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.Serialize(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.SerializeInternal(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)\r\n   at System.Net.Http.Formatting.BaseJsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStream(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, Encoding effectiveEncoding)\r\n   at System.Net.Http.Formatting.JsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStream(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, Encoding effectiveEncoding)\r\n   at System.Net.Http.Formatting.BaseJsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStream(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content)\r\n   at System.Net.Http.Formatting.BaseJsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStreamAsync(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content, TransportContext transportContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.WebHost.HttpControllerHandler.<WriteBufferedResponseContentAsync>d__22.MoveNext()","InnerException":{"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.","ExceptionType":"System.ObjectDisposedException","StackTrace":"   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.get_Connection()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.Execute(MergeOption mergeOption)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.EntityCollection`1.Load(List`1 collection, MergeOption mergeOption)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.EntityCollection`1.Load(MergeOption mergeOption)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd.DeferredLoad()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.LazyLoadBehavior.LoadProperty[TItem](TItem propertyValue, String relationshipName, String targetRoleName, Boolean mustBeNull, Object wrapperObject)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.LazyLoadBehavior.<>c__DisplayClass7`2.<GetInterceptorDelegate>b__1(TProxy proxy, TItem item)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.AspNetUser_4C1FDBB9E07016D6C527FBA4F5785F2C7FE37C77A86A5D1946B99CFFDE56DB7F.get_AspNetUserClaims()\r\n   at GetAspNetUserClaims(Object )\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DynamicValueProvider.GetValue(Object target)"}}}
```

***I want to know the reason of this anomaly, not any solution***, because it can be solved by returning a defined class, Like this =>

```
            User user = new User();
            AspNetUser data = entities.AspNetUsers.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName == id);
            user.reg_username = data.UserName;
            user.reg_email = data.Email;
            return user;
```

Comment: You are missing all the other tables Identity creates

Comment: @Stilgar Yes, I understand that, but I don't need those tables, and if that is the case, why I don't get any error while debugging step-wise. And, how to correct it?

Comment: Seems like an issue with lazy loading. When Web API tries to serialize the object it hits the properties which do not exist. Doesn't really explain why it works with a debugger though. Maybe the debugger hits the properties and silently swallows the exception and then EF treats them as loaded...